# Prepopulating a password field on jsp page

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form which sets the password to some user, 
I need to be able to pre-populate the password fields with a mask i.e. ****** value on edit that record.

Unfortunately, when I use form:password the value is not displayed
however, if I use form:input 
I can't see the mask and what I type into the form is not hidden...

Is there anyway to pre-populate form:password fields? Or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you never want to save the actual password - you only want a hash (salted md5, bcrypt). so you shouldn't actually KNOW the password. what you COULD do is populate it with a known value that you can recognize when it is posted, or just use an html placeholder:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="XXXXXXX">
```

which should show up as masked.

then your backend will have to check if a password is set, and if the field is empty, ignore it.

Comment: The fun part begins when you CAN have empty passwords. The placeholder doesn't work in that case since it won't detect emptying the password field.